# Error 'a value of type "X *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "X *"' when using typedef struct

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, typedef

Here is the struct I am using for the nodes...

```
typedef struct
{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* previous;
    void* data;
} Node;
```

and here is the function I am using to link them

```
void linkNodes(Node* first, Node* second)
{
    if (first != NULL)
        first->next = second;

    if (second != NULL)
        second->previous = first;
}
```

now visual studio is giving me the intellisense(less) error on those lines

```
IntelliSense: a value of type "Node *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Node *"
```

can anyone explain the proper way to do this? Visual studio will compile it and run it find and it also works on my mac but is crashing on my schools servers.

edit: i thought of using memcpy but that's pretty cheasy

Comment: Your error message is "wrong" as you report it here, it should be `"Node *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "struct Node *"`. Either you have a really bad compiler that confuses things (unlikely) this would show that you somehow happen to compile your code as C++. Don't do that, C and C++ are distinct languages, for which your problem is a good example.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem is there is no *struct* called Node, there is only a typedef.  Try

```
 typedef struct Node { ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Similar to Deepu's answer, but a version that will let your code compile. Change your struct to the following:

```
typedef struct Node // <-- add "Node"
{
    struct Node* next;
    struct Node* previous;
    void* data;
}Node; // <-- Optional

void linkNodes(Node* first, Node* second)
{    
    if (first != NULL)
        first->next = second;

    if (second != NULL)
        second->previous = first;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Defining `typedef` of `struct` in C is best done before the `struct` declaration itself.

```
typedef struct Node Node; // forward declaration of struct and typedef

struct Node
{
    Node* next;          // here you only need to use the typedef, now
    Node* previous;
    void* data;
};
```