# a value of type "Struct*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Struct*"

Tags: c++, pointers, struct

I've a function which returns a struct type pointer. What I want is pFacialFeatures to point to the same address as returned pointer.

```
struct Features
{
    CvRect* face_;
    CvRect* nose_;
    CvRect* eyesPair_;
    CvRect* rightEye_;
    CvRect* leftEye_;
    CvRect* mouth_;
};

Features* Detect()
{
    Features* facialFeatures = (Features*) malloc(sizeof(Features));
    return facialFeatures;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Features* pFacialFeatures;
    pFacialFeatures = Detect();
}
```

It gives me the error:

> IntelliSense: a value of type "Features *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Features *"

**Note:** Maybe you may think this question is same with this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595449/error-a-value-of-type-x-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of-type-x-when). In that question there's a problem with declaring struct. I declared struct truely.

Comment: It's C++ code. @BLUEPIXY

Comment: Could this be an intellisense issue? What happens if you go ahead and compile ?

Comment: There is no problem if C++. Are you trying to compile it as C?

Comment: IntelliSense sometimes shows you errors where there aren't any. The code compiles under VS11 (at least if I add a placeholder `struct CvRect {int i;};` to the code and include stdlib.h).

Comment: Does the code you posted cause that error, or is it just an approximation?

Comment: Of course cause that error @molbdnilo

Comment: @KMetin I asked because if you put that code in a file and compile, there will be more errors than that.

Comment: @molbdnilo to compile you have to add an implementation of `CvRect` and `#include <stdlib.h>` for malloc.

Comment: check project properties page language.

Comment: is all of this in a single file?

Comment: Make sure you `#include <cstdlib>` and either go `std::malloc` or `using namespace std;`

Comment: If it's C++, why are you using `malloc()`? Use `new`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have somehow informed Visual Studio that this is a C source file instead of a C++ source file - perhaps by naming the file "something.c" or by placing it in a header file and then including it from a ".h" file or by having a dangling "extern C" or by having somehow set the properties for the file or project to "Compile as C". If you're using Linux/MacOS, you've probably done it by using the C compiler instead of the C++ compiler, e.g. by typing "gcc foo.cpp" instead of "g++ foo.cpp"

The C language syntax for a struct declaration is different than that in C++.

The C++ statement

```
struct Foo {}; // C++
```

is equivalent to this in C:

```
typename struct tagFoo {} Foo; // C
```

So the following code would work in C++ but fail in C:

```
struct Foo {};
Foo* f = (Foo*)malloc(sizeof(Foo));
```

A quick way to change this to check for C++ is to replace:

```
Features* facialFeatures = (Features*) malloc(sizeof(Features));
```

with

```
Features* facialFeatures = new Features;
```

If you're compiling in C mode, you'll get a compiler error about `new`. It's a keyword in C++ but not in C.

The way to write your line in C is

```
struct Features* facialFeatures = malloc(sizeof* facialFeatures);
```

Comment: The way to write it in C is `struct Features *facialFeatures = malloc(sizeof *facialFeatures);`.  [Don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Answer (score -1):

I belive you need to put struct before the declaration of the type:

```
struct Features* facialFeatures = (struct Features *)malloc(sizeof(struct Features));
```