# Template object as class parameter gives error before compiling

Tags: c++, templates, compilation

Here is the code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class OwnerType>
class Move {
public:
    Move() {}
    Move(OwnerType &_owner) {
        owner = &_owner;
    }
    void GetPosition() {
        cout << owner->x << endl;
    }
    OwnerType *owner;
};

class Entity {
public:
    int x = 50;
    Move<Entity> *move;
};


int main() {        
    Entity en; 
    en.x = 77;
    en.move = new Move<Entity>(en);   // sign '=' is underlined by VS
    en.move->GetPosition();
    return 0;
}
```

Error it gives :

```
a value of type "Move<Entity> *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "Move<Entity> *"
```

The program is compiling, working as expected and gives expected values, however error is still here. 
It's probably something to do with templates and compiling time and stuff but I don't have enough knowledge to know what this error actually represents.

Also don't worry about leaks since this was just me testing, error is what I don't understand.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't trust the intellisense. Actually compile.

Comment: [OT]: Your program leaks.

Comment: `int main { ` is that in your actual code? Misses the `()`.

Comment: This was made just so I can test if something can be done so I didn't care much about deleting pointers, also I forgot () when copy-pasting somehow I'll correct it, but problem is error itself.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error 'a value of type "X \*" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "X \*"' when using typedef struct](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595449/error-a-value-of-type-x-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of-type-x-when)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intellisense is known for displaying invalid errors (see for example [Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense errors but solution compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles)), trust the compiler and linker, as suggested in comments.

However, this error is quite annoying, try closing the solution, delete the `.suo` file (it's hidden), and open in again. More info on what a `.suo` file is given here [Solution User Options (.Suo) File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb165909.aspx)

Side note, in your code example `main` is missing `()`.

Comment: Yes that explains pretty much everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

so it is not Error.

it is Intellisense : 
see:
[Error 'a value of type "X *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "X *"' when using typedef struct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595449/error-a-value-of-type-x-cannot-be-assigned-to-an-entity-of-type-x-when)

[Visual Studio 2015: Intellisense errors but solution compiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31943634/visual-studio-2015-intellisense-errors-but-solution-compiles)

---

old:

your `main` needs `()`:

this works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

template<class T> class Move {
public:
    Move() {}
    Move(T &_owner) {
        owner = &_owner;
    }
    void GetPosition() {
        cout << owner->x << endl;
    }
    T *owner;
};

class Entity {
public:
    int x = 50;
    Move<Entity> *move;
};


int main(){
    Entity en;
    en.x = 77;
    en.move = new Move<Entity>(en);   // sign '=' is underlined by VS
    en.move->GetPosition();

    return 0;
}
```

output:

```
77
```

Comment: OP says it works, it's the invalid error which bugs him

Comment: It works fine but gives error even before compiling, also I forgot to say that Visual Studio 2015 is used.

Comment: Intellisense  it is. Thanks for help.